# why the page  refresh a time?

Tags: javascript

```
<form method="get"  action="/" onsubmit="SubmitForm()">
<input type="text" title="" value="" name="q" class="search-input" id="gsearch" />
<input type="submit" value="" name="sa" id="search-button"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitForm(){
window.open("http://test.com/gsearch.php?cx=015214977:8tebxhu0mrk&cof=FORID:11&ie=GB2312&as_q="+document.getElementById('gsearch').value);
return false;
}

</script>
```

when i submit the button, the original page refresh a time. how to prevent it? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your form onsubmit attribute and insert a *return* like this:

```
<form method="get"  action="/" onsubmit="return SubmitForm();">
```

Comment: The onsubmit attribute is a javascript script. the form will not be submitted if that script return false. At the first, your script was _SubmitForm()_ which just called the function, And there were no _return false_. But after inserting a return, now in onsubmit script, you return the return value of SubmitForm, which is false.

Answer (score 3):

You correctly return false from your `SubmitForm` method, but you're not capturing that response in the `onsubmit` handler of the form. Change it to this:

```
<form method="get"  action="/" onsubmit="return SubmitForm()">
```

Note the addition of the `return` keyword in the above.

Comment: @zhuanzhou - For the exact reasons I specified in my answer. But seeing as you accepted the answer with *far* less info, I wont bother trying to explain it again

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use JavaScript for this. This will work same way:

```html
<form method="get" target="_blank" action="http://test.com/gsearch.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="015214977:8tebxhu0mrk" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:11" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="GB2312" />
    <input type="text" title="" value="" name="as_q" class="search-input" id="gsearch" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="search-button"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript is all nice and good, but really no need to use it when plain HTML can do the same thing exactly.